# MVC Scaffolding PowerShell Commands

Tags: asp.net-mvc, powershell, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

MVC Scaffolding used to expose a set of powershell commands for generating a lot of goodness from the Package Manager Console.

It seems that the PS commands have been eschewed in the 2013 release and instead they are individual templates that run via the VS Add-item menus.

On a prior project, (ca. four years ago) I leveraged scaffolding heavily as a means of meta-programming. We had customized the T4 templates and even produced our own commands to generate structures that were specific to our project. Most of our coding was focused around domain objects and we'd scaffold new stuff after the domain object was fleshed out. From there, it was mostly minor tweaks to the generated code to do stuff that was specific for the given scenario.

Is it possible to still use powershell for scaffolding or has that gone away? The MVC Scaffolding nuget package hasn't been published since 2012. Would it be possible to start there, and update it to support VS 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to download the right version for vs-2013.

MvcScaffolding 1.0.8-vs2013 from nuget.

Comment: Sorry I took so long to mark your answer as correct.